# errors in code noob cant fix them

Tags: codeigniter, variables, foreach, php

I am working on a small application that displays data from a database table. I am getting 2 errors and dont know why are there, and I cant figure it out as I am still a noob. I guess its something stupid, please help.

**ERRORS**

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: querys


Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

these errors are located in my view page.

**VIEW**

```
    <?php foreach ($queries as $row): ?>
    <table>

       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Surname</th>
       <th>phone</th>
       <th>email</th>

       <td><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $row->surname; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $row->phone; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $row->email; ?></td>

   </table>  
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
  function display($offset = 0)
    {
           $limit = 20;
            $this->load->model('info_model');

            $results = $this->info_model->search($limit, $offset);

            $data['queries'] = $results['rows'];
            $data['num_results'] = $results['num_rows'];


            $this->load->view('info_view',$data);


    }
```

**MODEL**

```
 function search ($limit, $offset){

          //results query 
          $q = $this->db->select('ID, name, surname, phone, email');
          $this->db->from('tblinfo');
          $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);

          $ret['rows'] = $q->get()->result();
          //count query
          $q = $this->db->select('COUNT(*) as count', FALSE )
          ->from('tblinfo');

          $tmp = $q->get()->result();

          $ret['num_rows'] = $tmp[0]->count;
          return $ret;
      }
```

**EDIT**

i fixed the foreach error by inserting

```
   <?php if(is_array($queries)): ?>
   <?php endif; ?>
```

the only error i am getting is the

```
   A PHP Error was encountered

    Severity: Notice

    Message: Undefined variable: queries
```

Comment: you never defined $querys

Comment: what do u mean by 4 ?

Comment: if this is the begining of the code then its obvious error. there must be some code written on top of it. where is it?

Comment: The following might be helpful for you: [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12769982/367456)

Comment: Its `query`, not `querys`.

Comment: `$data['query'] = $results['rows'];` but instead of using `query` in the view, you use `querys`. Probably not the only error, but seems like a typo.

Comment: no i tryed to change querys to query i am getting the same two errors

Comment: Is your results being passed properly? $data['query'] = $results['rows'];  I am not sure if you are actually getting the array passed over to the view.  Prior to doing the foreach ($query as $row) I would add if (is_array($query)) { foreach ($query as $row) {...}}

Comment: Not sure why this is being downvoted? The OP asks a very easy to understand question, and provides all the code needed to solve it??

Comment: i tried var_dump it returns a null

Comment: i did try that but it not change anything same 2 errors are showing up

Comment: I would focus on the query and returning the data from the model -> controller and just edit your $query variable typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I think a function should perform only one task. Right now you are trying to do two tasks (return records and return a record count) in one function.

I would rewrite my model like this:

```
function search($limit, $offset)
{
  $this->db->select('ID, name, surname, phone, email');
  $this->db->from('tblinfo');
  $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
  return $this->db->get();
}
```

And your controller could look like this:

```
function display($offset = 0)
{
  $this->load->model('info_model');
  $results = $this->info_model->search(20, $offset);

  $data['queries'] = $results->result();
  $data['num_results'] = $this->db->count_all('tblinfo'); // Alternatively you could make a separate model function that does this

  $this->load->view('info_view', $data);
}
```

Comment: tnx fore answering but its the same error when i tried Undefined variable: queries

Comment: @user2143150, could you try again with exactly the code above? This *should* work.

Comment: its the same error tnx for the effort

Comment: @user2143150, sorry, I spotted one more mistake... I forgot `return` in the model. Please try again.

Comment: same error again is there a simpler way maybe to retrieve records from table instead of my version of the code ?

Comment: @user2143150, what do you mean? I don't understand your question.

Comment: all i am trying is to display the data that is on a table in a database. is there a simpler way of doing this instead of the code that i have ?

Comment: @user2143150, this is pretty basic already and it *should* work. Are you sure your `display` function gets called? Could you add the following to the top of your `display` function? `echo 'this is display'; exit;` and tell me what happens?

Comment: @user2143150 - Glad to hear it! Just wondering... what was the problem?

Comment: like u said the display function was not getting called that's why the unused variable there so i changed my code little bit and it worked. tnx for your help bdw

Answer (score 5):

```
$data['query'] = $results['rows'];
```

should be

```
$data['querys'] = $results['rows']; // although correct spelling is "queries"
```

Then you can access `$querys` inside your view.

Comment: that dose not work i already triad that but tnx for answering

Comment: @user2143150 This is the answer to why you were getting an error saying that `$querys` was not defined. If it's not working, tell us why? Is there a new error message? It could be possible, that your database query doesn't return any results?

Comment: no the error messages do not change they are the same as in above question

Comment: i did try this before posting this question

Comment: This is one of the problems with your code above. The other, is most likely that your model isn't getting any data.

Comment: I think he shouldn't be returning two values via an array workaround, but this is indeed the main problem.

Comment: in my code i forgot to include i have a form_open(); if that makes any difference ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be with your models `search()` method, which is probably not returning any results. I would re-write it as follows to utilize codeigniters active record class:

```
function search ($limit, $offset){

    //results query 
    $this->db->select('ID, name, surname, phone, email');
    $q =  $this->db->get('tblinfo', $limit, $offset);

    $ret['rows'] = $q->result();

    //count query
    $ret['num_rows'] = $this->db->count_all('tblinfo');

    return $ret;
}
```

You can use Codeigniters [active record class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) to get a count of all records in a specific table using just `$this->db->count_all('table_name');`

Comment: I would fix typo ret['rows'] to $ret['rows']

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change your search code a little

```
$q = $this->db->select('ID, name, surname, phone, email')
              ->from('tblinfo')
              ->limit($limit, $offset);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your model code to this

```
function search ($limit, $offset){

      //results query 
      $this->db->select('ID, name, surname, phone, email');
      $this->db->from('tblinfo');
      $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
      $q = $this->db->get();
      $ret['rows'] = $q->result();
      //count query
      $q1 = $this->db->select('COUNT(*) as count', FALSE )
      ->from('tblinfo');

      $tmp = $q1->get()->result();

      $ret['num_rows'] = $tmp[0]->count;
      return $ret;
  }
```